# Eigenvalues of an Infinite Matrix - No Diagonal Dominance

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I was wondering if anyone could help me or point me to resources to find the eigenvalue of the following infinite matrix: $g_{ij}=\text{exp}\left(\frac{-i j}{2}\right)$.

Most resources I have found have required diagonal dominance, which this matrix does not have. Thanks!

Comment: What is the range of $i, j$?

Comment: both are 0 to infinity